# Updating a variable with a button

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to add 7 days to a date everytime the user clicks on a button.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # Just checking your Python version to import Tkinter properly.
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk as ttk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.ttk import ttk as ttk
import datetime
import calendar

def nextweek(cd, ow):
    newdate=(cd+ow)
    cd=newdate
    return cd
def printdate(cd):
    print cd

curdate = datetime.date(2016, 01, 04)
one_week = datetime.timedelta(weeks = 1)

root = tk.Tk()
bls = ttk.Style()
bls.configure('Black.TLabelframe', background="#222222")

dayframe = ttk.Button(root, text="Hello", command=lambda: nextweek(curdate, one_week))
dayframe.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
dayframetest = ttk.Button(root, text="test", command=lambda: printdate(curdate))
dayframetest.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5)
root.mainloop()
```

All the examples I saw so far use global variables, is there a way to do it without making curdate a global?

Comment: problem is because `Button` executes function but it can't receive returned values so you can't assing to `curdate` returned value. You can put all in one class and use `self.`.

Comment: BTW, your syntax for python 3 is wrong. This code won't execute on python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally better to use an Object Oriented approach to creating tkinter applications. I've taken your example and modified it so that the curdate is stored inside the App class.

N.B. I tested it on python3.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # Just checking your Python version to import Tkinter properly.
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk as ttk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import datetime
import calendar

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        bls = ttk.Style()
        bls.configure('Black.TLabelframe', background="#222222")

        self.dayframe = ttk.Button(self, text="Hello", command= self.nextweek)
        self.dayframe.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.dayframetest = ttk.Button(self, text="test", command= self.printdate)
        self.dayframetest.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5)

        self.curdate = datetime.date(2016, 1, 4)
        self.one_week = datetime.timedelta(weeks = 1)

    def nextweek(self):
        self.curdate = (self.curdate + self.one_week)

    def printdate(self):
        print(self.curdate)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works however that button is going to have to update a lot more variables from different objects...so putting everything in one big class might be messy...

Comment: Which is why you use object oriented programming. The App class can contain an instance of other classes. For example you might have one class to store dates, one to store lists of people, another for a checklist. You can even have a list of instances of classes. Then the App class can call the update method for each class when the button is pressed. Doing it this way is much better than having random variable randomly throughout your code. Group similar variables and the methods that modify them in to classes.